# Windows().Activate does not seem to be working. How to fix "requested member does not exist?"

Tags: vba, variables, ms-word

I have a personal macro in Word VBA which I can use on any document. The macro will switch between 2 word docs, so I define the first file with a variable and use the windows().activate function to return to that file. However, this doesn't always seem to work. I've simplified the code below to just show what isn't working. What am I doing wrong here? Am I defining the variable wrong? The error I'm getting is "Run-time error 5941: The requested member of the collection does not exist."

```
Sub mainfile()

Dim mainfile As String

mainfile = ActiveDocument.Name

Windows(mainfile).Activate

End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: activedocument.name is the full name of the document including the file extension - windows(x) refers to the title of the window holding the document - if the window title doesn't include the file extension they won't match. Why not declare a document variable, set that to activedocument and then later just use mydocument,activate?

Comment: @HarassedDad - re: "Why not declare a document variable, set that to activedocument and then later just use mydocument,activate?" - how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

@Harassed Dad - This is what worked based on your comment, thank you!

```
Sub mainfile()

Dim mainfile As Document

Set mainfile = ActiveDocument

mainfile.Activate

End Sub
```